# Why is this question closed as "unclear what you are asking"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, unclear

I have come upon "[Locker Room Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866582/locker-room-algorithm)" today. I don't think it is unclear, the only thing I fixed was that it was not really about C. Still I think it is a perfectly valid question and does not deserve to be downvoted or closed. Can anyone justify why it is "unclear"?

Recently I have noticed that many questions about algorithms get downvoted and closed, and I definitely don't like the tendency. Closing and downvoting the question of a newcomer to the site without giving a justification destroys the reputation of the community.

Comment: If I had to say, it'd be because there was no code, as the first comment mentioned.

Comment: @WaiHaLee but the question is "is this algorithm correct" there is pseudo code which is perfectly fine for an algorithm question

Comment: @Deduplicator it may be a bad thing, but downvoting and closing the question without explaining what the issue is does no good.

Comment: On a programming Q&A site, 'validation' would, to me, mean implementing the algorithm and testing it on a computer.   That is way off-topic/too broad/something.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: *Please* don't open that pandora's box. While in some questions you are right with that, namely when those two actions are evidently questionable, most times doing so would just be wasting more time.

Comment: @Deduplicator that is not a  Pandora's box situation.   SO is so full of bad questions that there is no room for hope:(

Comment: @MartinJames: Ouch. You shouldn't shatter my illusions, I have few enough left as-is.

Comment: @MartinJames for algorithm tag pseudo code should be considered enough to describe the question. Implementing actual code will limit the question to a given language(which may not be desirable) and will also be wasting time. Pseudo code is, for me, easier to parse and understand in many cases.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev yeah.. in this case... maybe,, whatever:)  On this question, I think I'll stick with my original decision and just not vote on it at all, no up, no down, no close.   I certainly would not want to discourage all algorithm/pseudocode questions.

Comment: [**A run down on close reasons, with pictures!**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/213575)

Comment: *Closing and downvoting the question of a newcomer to the site without giving a justification destroys the reputation of the community.* - every closed question gets an explanation why it was closed and how to fix it or avoid it in the future. Not actively down voting and voting to close things that are off-topic for **whatever reason** harms the reputation of the community.

Comment: IMO the question should have been migrated to [programmers.se], it's a perfect fit for it.

Comment: The question may be a bit broad, but I'll give it this: it sure has balls.

Comment: Things I look for in a "good" question: 1) what have you tried? 2) which specific step didn't work?... In this case the answers are: 1) you tried nothing. 2) you don't know if it works, or doesn't work, or even if you have any problem in the first place.  -  So I would join the "close vote" team for whichever reason gets nominated. Personally, if I cared to get involved, I would go for **too broad**

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev When a question is put on hold or closed, an explanation (the chosen close reason) is automatically attached.  Leaving comments is nice, but should never be considered compulsory.  And when someone doesn't understand why the question is closed (or disagrees) after reading that attached message, well... questions like this meta are the exactly appropriate response.

Comment: while I agree "what have you tried?" is useful to discourage help vampires, it should not be necessary to all questions because the most important property of a question is its context

Comment: Reopened. last vote from me ;)

Answer (score 18):

> Why is this question closed as “unclear what you are asking”?

Great question. Though, somewhat moot as the question is no longer closed as "unclear what you are asking". I do think the question is reasonably *clear*, in terms of understanding what kind of answer the question is intended to elicit.

Explaining the "unclear" close votes definitively is impossible, except by asking those who voted that way. We have no way to see the individual voting history for the earlier closing of the question; it's possible there were a couple of "too broad" votes, but of course at least three of the five votes must have been for "unclear".

Perhaps one person did find the question unclear and two others followed suit because they were trigger-happy to get rid of a question that they intuitively felt should be closed but hadn't thought in depth enough about *why* it should be closed. Maybe all three votes were from such people, just using "unclear" as their default for "I don't like this question but I'm not willing to put enough effort in to figure out why."

On the other hand, perhaps the voters looked at the question and determined that the single interrogative sentence in the question was probably *not* really the only thing that the owner of the question intended to ask, but found it unclear as to what exactly that owner did mean to ask. I.e. the question as posted was in fact legitimately unclear to them.

You'd have to ask each of them directly, to know for sure why they voted that way.

That said, the question does seem clearly "too broad" to me, and has in fact now been closed using that reason. If nothing else, the *"Looking forward to any comments, suggestions and inputs"* is explicitly soliciting an overly broad discussion and debate about the question, rather than a simple "yes" or "no" answer (which is all that would be seen if the primary question were taken literally).

One signal that the question is poor and inappropriate for Stack Overflow is that its sole tag is [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm), which is hardly a good, descriptive tag. It tells you basically nothing about the question that would distinguish the question from other questions on Stack Overflow. Maybe this is just a case of the owner of the question failing to find a better, usefully descriptive tag. But it's definitely not a good sign.

In fact, one of the other things the question suffers from is a complete lack of evidence that the owner of the question made any real effort to research the question. It didn't take me long at all to find several articles on the web that address this popular programming puzzle, and yet the question doesn't mention even trying such a search, never mind describing what they found and what *specifically* they were having trouble understanding.

So, yes…I suppose you technically have answered the single phrase in the post that had a question mark. But it's likely that's not really all the OP was asking for. Indeed, telling them that their proposed algorithm doesn't work probably doesn't get them to where they want to be; now they will require a whole series of follow-up discussion to arrive at an algorithm that *does* work. It's that discussion that also is a hallmark of a question that's too broad.

I'm sorry if you feel your efforts have been diminished in some way by the poor response that the question got. For better or worse, one of the *primary* functions of the Stack Overflow community is not to *answer* questions, but rather to evaluate the questions critically, and make sure the question really is a well-researched, on-topic question that deserves an answer. To answer a question before being really certain of that is to risk the rest of the community voting down and/or closing the question (or in some cases even your answer…especially if you seem to not have really offered a complete answer to an overly broad question) due to the poor quality of the question.

Comment: do you agree to destroy "algorithm" tag?

Comment: @amuse: I don't understand the question. It's not within my power to unilaterally eliminate all uses of [tag:algorithm]. If you mean, would I object to it being burninated? No, I would not object. See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ for a more detailed discussion of why that tag and others like it are not useful.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I personally quite like the `algorithm` tag, or rather its content. Algorithmic questions need not specify a language, an algorithm after all is not programming language dependent: it's a mathematical construct! Whether `algorithm` is the best name possible is moot, but its content is not meta as far as I am concerned and I see no issue with it being the sole tag of a question.

Answer (score 7):

OP brought a problem, suggested a solution and finally came with the question:

> My question is am I right?

While the question *is* clear, I still think it should be closed, but for another reason (too broad?). Simply asking "am I right" when suggesting a solution for an algorithmic problem is not really well defined, specially when no attempt to prove its correctness.

I would have upvoted if OP was more specific, not just posting an algorithm (that's not really detailed) and asks us if it's correct (the same holds for questions that that ask if the code works).

Comment: Hmm I don't agree. In my opinion there are two possible answers to OP's question - "yes your algorithm is correct and here is a proof" and "No your algorithm is not correct, here is a counter example".

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Then why do we close questions asking "is my code correct"?

Comment: I have two points here - a code can be run by the poster instead of posting on a website and thus they can verify it on their own easily. In many cases an algorithm can't. Second in many cases a question of the type "is my code correct" does not at all describe what the code is supposed to be doing. Just asking is this code correct is too broad of course. It will always be as it does precisely what you told it to. This is my interpretation and of course it may not be entirely correct

Comment: I don't think pseudocode is far more specific than text at this case, unless the text description is not clear (If you think the text description is not clear, I hope it is not because you know nothing about locker room algorithm)

Comment: i'll be honest, in recent years the fun element of SO has evapourated. in days gone by, you could ask/answer questions that were borderline and still find that it addressed the problem once stealth wit and wisdom was woven into the detail. as things now stand, make one grammatical error and you're instantly either edited (game players), or voted to close (ok, taking it a bit far). my point is that the personality on SO has been largely humour bypassed, in favour of homogonized content - (sad face icon).

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: Let's be honest here; "Am I right?" is a terrible question from any perspective.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev correctness and being optimal are very different properties of algorithm (and your answer to actual question looks unrelated to me). OP did not clarify what (if any) help is needed - correct algorithm is must for interview question like that, so simple yes/no answer should be enough.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: *In my opinion there are two possible answers to OP's question* is simply ridiculous justification. By your logic, a valid question would be *Is it possible to use a computer to solve world hunger?*, to which there are two possible answers, yes and no. The logic is ludicrous for a technical site such as SO, and a question asking *Am I right?* should be answered by the instructor that posed the question to that student. If we open the door to that type of question, it benefits no one and increases clutter and noise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So should "Am I right?" be modified to  "Is there a better way?" or something else?

Comment: @Identity1 It'll still be "too broad" in this case.

Comment: @Ivaylo I don't see any pseudocode in the question. IMHO what he has is just a description - pseudocode to me is much more specific, and can be likened to programming code.

Comment: Posting an algorithm with the question "Am I right?" belongs on codereview.SE

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev doesn't the OP's follow up comment on your answer show that they were not asking only for the answer you gave?  Clearly they were seeking, or at least have realized a need for a larger discussion.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev The Collatz conjecture is true.  Am I right?  (Note that neither counter examples, nor saying "yes", are reasonable answers)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I remember someone posting a code snippet and asking if it was correct - and he was shot off to code review

Answer (score 4):

*Unclear* not, **too broad²** for sure.

I would vote to close and prompt him/her to the [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) or maybe the [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Just because there is another site which scope overlaps with SO, doesn't necessarily make a question off-topic on SO.

Comment: @Lundin But the question is not about actual programming but about theory. Algorithm correctness is as much related to programming as to pure Maths. So I'd definitely move the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  The question is about a software algorithm, so it is explicitly on-topic. We should not migrate on-topic questions to other sites.

Comment: If not these questions, then do not expect the other sites to bloom.-

Comment: @gsamaras You'd close an on-topic question just to force the OP to go forth and populate the barren wasteland that is TCS.SE?

Comment: But if this is as you say @Sneftel, then why to have the other sites too? Probably to fit other questions you are going to argue..and that's OK. :)

Comment: @Lundin: the question is not about **software** algorithm. It just describes algorithm for *abstract* task, which *can be coded or not*. Example of algorithmic question, which has been successfully migrated to Computer Science today: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52108/shortest-path-in-divisors-graph

Answer (score 2):

If you're not sure about an algorithm, then try to express that algorithm in the highest level language you can get your hands on. Then it becomes a topical StackOverflow question with code.

Questions about algorithms in which the algorithm is only described informally waste everyone's time on issues related to how the informal description maps to a formal one that can execute.

Questions like "will this algorithm work" will sometimes answer themselves if the description is implemented. Testing will show whether the correct answers are coming out.

Informal descriptions are tedious to test, and error-prone. Even for small inputs, an algorithm might involve executing hundreds or thousands of steps. If you run these steps manually, you can easily make mistakes. These mistakes could wrongly convince you that the algorithm is incorrect (false negative) or correct (false positive).  Unimplemented algorithms can only be feasibly verified using proofs, which are a waste of effort on something that isn't going to be an earth-shattering new algorithm in the annals of computer science. Before you can apply proof techniques, you probably have to make the description more rigorous, perhaps to the point that you have it in a pseudo-code language that could, in principle, directly execute. You might as well put that effort into coding it up in a high level language that is almost like textbook pseudo-code.

If you have a new idea for a sorting algorithm, you can simply code it up, and plug it into a test harness which generates random sequences of items, and detects that the output of the function reproduces all the times and that they are ordered.  Hammer on all the corner cases: empty sequence, sequences of one, two and three items, with all possible patterns of repetition and permutation.

If something is going wrong that you can't debug, you can then ask about it in terms of debugging help for a concrete piece of code.

Once you are confident that the high level rendition of the algorithm is correct, you can then translate it to whatever language you're actually working with (like C or whatever).

Comment: An "informal description" *is* the highest level language I can get my hands on. English is considerably more concise than Python, and doesn't suffer from fencepost bugs.

Comment: @Sneftel English absolutely suffers from fencepost bugs and worse. It suffers from terrible ambiguity. English sentences can easily be written which have two meanings due to an ambiguous syntactic parse, and even a syntactically unambiguous sentence can have multiple meanings through use of figures of speech (metaphor, irony, symbolism, ...).

Comment: Can, yes. You can write poorly in any language. The problem there is the quality of the writing, not the language.

Comment: @Sneftel Programming languages are either unambiguous (like Lisp), or are ostensibly ambiguous, with resolving rules (like which if is matched by a given else).  Therefore, you cannot write an ambiguity, period.  Moreover syntax errors, are automatically checked.  That is the point; repairing and revising a poor quality piece of technical writing is an off-topic waste of time in StackOverflow.  A question about an algorithm should be translated into unambiguous code, and edited to be free of those trivial errors that are easily diagnosed by machine implementations of that language.